# Align items on opposite directions to fit to smaller screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to align my brand and the rest of the links on the opposite side(brand on left and other links on the right) to fit on the mobile view but the links on the right move to the next line. Any suggestions will help thanks.I'm using bootstrap 5. Here's my code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="nav-navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">                    
                    <div class="col border border-danger">
                        <div class="d-sm-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
                            <button
                            class="navbar-toggler align-items-sm-start"
                            type="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                            >
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand name</a>            
                            <div class="d-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Search</div>
                                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">cart</div>
                                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Login</div>
                                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Sign up</div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>            
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"
                                    >NEW ITEMS</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">BRANDS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CURATED PIECES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">TOP ITEMS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">FEATURED</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>                
                </nav>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those items are wrapping to next line at the extra small breakpoint (or < small) because you are using `.d-sm-flex`. The display is only set to flex at the small and larger breakpoints.

To enable the flex behavior for all screen sizes use `.d-flex`.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors

You also have a couple of issues with your code that I have corrected in the snippet.

- `.col`s should be direct descendants of `.row`s
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/#how-they-work
- The scripts (popper.js & bootstrap.js) should be included just before the closing `</body>` tag after all content elements.
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#js

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="nav-navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light col">
        <div class="border border-danger">
          <div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
            <button class="navbar-toggler align-items-sm-start" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand name</a>
            <div class="d-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Search</div>
              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">cart</div>
              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Login</div>
              <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Sign up</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">NEW ITEMS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">BRANDS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CURATED PIECES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">TOP ITEMS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">FEATURED</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. Ive noticed the meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 is affecting the layout which was initially my code. Ive tried using the width to 320 its working dont know if this is good practice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 5, you can go to https://getbootstrap.com/ and use the top nav bar to navigate to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/. In here, you'll find an example page called "Headers", located here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/headers/.

These example headers could be a great resource for you to model your code after.

One other helpful resource is the Bootstrap 5 nav bar component page found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/

There are several examples on this page that could give you some ideas.

If you are new to HTML, CSS and/or Bootstrap, I would suggest starting off with one of their examples/templates and modifying rather than building your own.

Side note: it may also help if your code is more readable. You could put your code through an HTML formatter like: https://webformatter.com/html or use software like https://prettier.io/docs/en/.

Best of luck!

Comment: I am using their examples but ive edited it to what i would want it to look like.(added flex to the link thats meant to be on the right). The headers page has what i want but its still moving to the next line when i choose a mobile view.